# Swiper, only reload/refresh fixes display issue

Tags: swiper.js

Bump. Any idea? Thank you!

-

Displaying 3 slides/images per view, looped, centered.

With a clean cache, Swiper starts with the last slide and misses the first to the right. Browser refresh seems to fix it: swiper starts/initializes with first slide, no blank slides remain.

The amount of images is dynamic.

UPDATE:

The issue is with the CSS we added:

```
.swiper-container {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
}

.swiper-slide {
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0;
}

.swiper-slide img {
    height: 550px;
    width: auto;
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(1n) {
    height: 550px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Removing the very last bit (nth-child) resets the slider to always start with the first slide. But the images stop sitting next to each other, but instead are spread apart.

Created this to demonstrate a little quicker:

http://jsfiddle.net/L3b1fzh9/13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the last few lines of CSS, because `.swiper-slide:nth-child(1n)` matches every single `.swiper-slide` element, so this selector doesn't actually do anything (*n* is a set of all integers, so when you multiply by 1 you just get 0, 1, 2, etc.).

The reason why the images stop sitting next to each other is that their parent container `.swiper-slide` has `width: 100%`. You need to change that to `width: auto` and add `margin: 0 auto` to center the slides.

So your `.swiper-slide` CSS becomes:

```
.swiper-slide {
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0;
  width: auto !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And just remove the `.swiper-slide:nth-child(1n)` CSS.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marshmeryl/L3b1fzh9/161/)

Comment: Offering advice is okay in an answer, but you didn't exactly answer his question. If you want to earn reputation, you are more likely to do so if you elaborate in your answer and try to actually fix the problem.

Comment: @marshmeryl Just realized that we actually needed "width: 100%" on the parent container for the responsive part, but were easily able to adapt by a media-query. Thanks, again! That really helped.